# How do you pass query parameters to a GET endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple Lambda function that for now returns the event. So when I test with this, I return **event.body.url** and **event.body.wepbSupport**. That works in the AWS Lambda test environment.

TEST

```
{
  "body": {
    "url": "https://someURL.com",
    "webpSupport": true
  }
}
```

RESPONSE

```
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
  "url": "https://someURL.com",
  "webpSupport": true
}
```

I have no idea how to pass this query string to the staging [API Gateway staging URL](https://8fjr1z62c4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/foo). All the documentation from AWS shows an old interface that they've changed. I see add [URL Query String Parameters](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/pass-api-gateway-rest-api-parameters/) in these instructions but don't see that anywhere in the new interface.

Cloudwatch logs show me this:

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "The \"url\" argument must be of type string. Received undefined",
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The \"url\" argument must be of type string. Received undefined",
        "    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)",
        "    at Url.parse (url.js:170:3)",
        "    at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:157:13)",
        "    at dispatchHttpRequest (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:91:22)",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "    at httpAdapter (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:46:10)",
        "    at dispatchRequest (/var/task/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:52:10)",
        "    at async Promise.all (index 0)",
        "    at async Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:4:28)"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the event object I see that all GET query parameters are passed in **event.queryStringParameters**. Leaving this on the site in case anyone else stumbles across this question.